# Won't it be better if "Next" , "Previous" arrows have question title?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, navigation-arrows

Won't it be better if next, previous arrow have question title?

If you have no idea what is next, prev arrows, check this:

[image]

**Why ?**

See, I can already see arrow Left, arrow Right means previous and next question without need of a title.

But it would be better if I get to know Question title of next, previous question. Thanks.

Comment: If I go to [that page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316183/mysql-optimize-query) I don't have those buttons. Do you have some script that adds them running/

Comment: @Anthon , hello , if you hit url manually , it Wont show arrows . Go to -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql?sort=newest  Click any one of the question and you will see Arrows.

Comment: Why downvotes ? This is necessary functionality , every one knows Left means previous and Right arrow means next question. Almost every site has Title on next , prev button or moreover, it also has thumbnail of heading image for particular post. Please speak up.

Comment: I  still don't get those arrows, even if I go in via that URL and click a question.

Comment: @Anthon , everyone experienced it on this site.

Comment: I can see those arrows on some questions.

Comment: @Anthon My understanding is that it's in A/B testing. Not everyone will see it yet.

Comment: Guys, those close votes are incorrect. It's clear what he's asking (add text in the buttons), and the "Issue" _can_ be reproduced. Please cancel those votes.

Comment: While I'm with you about it would be nice to know where we're going, I also see the point that anyway you can't skip next question if it doesn't fit your interests. I would prefer an option to not show those arrows at all.

Comment: @Kaiido `I would prefer an option to not show those arrows at all.` , please just dont look at the arrows **`:)`** .

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com yeah just like I don't listen to my neighbor's daughter learning violin...

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com you probably also already have the href value displayed in the bottom of your page. You could guess from the url the question title.

Comment: @Kaiido , yes but still I want title attribute , it is legitimate for showing info about something .

Answer (score 4):

Those buttons already have `title` attributes saying *"previous question"* and *"next question"*. I really don't see the added value of having those titles displayed in the buttons themselves.

Frankly, I think it'd be ugly.

Here's the current HTML from a random question:

[image]

Comment: `Frankly, I think it'd be ugly` , No , it wont, I see monst of the questions are having small Question Title , check =>  http://stackoverflow.com/questions . Almost 80% question titles  have less than  10 ,12 words so, it wont be ugly. And we also can have option like `'This is some big question ti........'` etc